# Extending connected stateful connected component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I would like to create a base Redux component with its own state and properties. When I extend it in a generic way, I want to merge the extended object's properties and state also with the base. This component has to be connected with my Redux store.

I've created some snippet, that works for properties, but not for states.

BaseComponent:

```js
import * as React from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { IRootState } from "../../../Store/ApplicationStore";

interface IComponentStoreProps {
    storeProp?: boolean;
}

interface IComponentOwnState {
    myState?: string | number;
}

class BaseComponent<Props, State> extends React.Component<Props & IComponentStoreProps, State & IComponentOwnState> {
    constructor(props: Props & IComponentStoreProps) {
        super(props);
    }
}

export const BaseComponentConnected = <Props, State>() => {
    return connect(
        (state: IRootState): any => {
            return {
                storeProp: state.global.tfsRelatedData.isLoaded
            };
        }
    )(BaseComponent as new () => BaseComponent<Props & IComponentStoreProps, State & IComponentOwnState>);
};
```

ExtendedComponent:

```js
interface IComponentOwnState {
    fieldValue: string;
}

interface IComponentStoreProps {
    isLoaded: boolean;
}

class ExtendedComponent extends BaseComponentConnected<IComponentStoreProps, IComponentOwnState>() {
 //this.props.isLoaded   -> exists
 //this.props.storeProp  -> exists
 //this.state            -> undefined
}
```

How can I create a merged state object in the inherited classes?

In case if I export the unconnected component, everything works fine and I would like to do the same with my connected one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by what you are trying to do. You are trying to get a "father" component to makes changes in a "son" component - this goes against the whole purpose of state vs. props.  A component's state should only matter to it - no one else should be able to access it, let alone modify it. As per the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html):

> React has a powerful composition model, and we recommend using composition instead of inheritance to reuse code between components.

If you wish to provide additional values as props to components, I'd suggest the patterns of [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), or a custom [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

If you insist on using an inheritance model, my answer to you is this - you should merge the state yourself, possibly in the constructor of the component. I can't find initialization anywhere in your code, so I can only assume it should stay undefined (after all, you must defined it somewhere).